# Laravel Test with PHP Unit - Type not supported for file testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm using Laravel 10 with Livewire 2. I was writing a simple test for a component, which is just an upload form. I ran into a cryptic message error:

```
FAILED  Tests\Feature\Livewire\UploadAssetTest > book can be saved correctly                                                             
Type is not supported

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php:88
     84▕             default => json_encode($data, $this->encodingOptions),
     85▕         };
     86▕ 
     87▕         if (! $this->hasValidJson(json_last_error())) {
  ➜  88▕             throw new InvalidArgumentException(json_last_error_msg());
     89▕         }
     90▕ 
     91▕         return $this->update();
     92▕     }
```

The test is:

```
    /** @test */
    public function book_can_be_saved_correctly()
    {
        $admin = User::factory()->create();
        $this->actingAs($admin);

        Storage::fake('private');

        $testBook = UploadedFile::fake()->create('private/books/test_book.pdf');
        $testCover = UploadedFile::fake()->image('private/covers/test_image.png');

        $emptyForm = (new UploadBookService())->buildForm();

        $book = array_merge($emptyForm,[
            'title' => 'Title Test',
            'author' => 'Author Test',
            'description' => 'Description Test',
            'publishedAt' => '2022',
            'cover' => $testCover,
            'book' => $testBook,
        ]);

        $component = Livewire::test(UploadAsset::class)
            ->set('assetMeta', $book)
            ->call('save');

            Storage::assertExists('books/test_book.pdf');
            Storage::assertExists('covers/test_cover.png');
    }
```

For what I've debugged so far, the error is triggered once i call `set()` in the test.
I can confirm that the component is working while using it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are passing a value that is not compatible with the json_encode() function, I suggest the following:

```
$book = array_merge($emptyForm,[
    'title' => 'Title Test',
    'author' => 'Author Test',
    'description' => 'Description Test',
    'publishedAt' => '2022',
    'coverPath' => 'private/covers/test_image.png',
    'bookPath' => 'private/books/test_book.pdf', 
]);

$component = Livewire::test(UploadAsset::class)
    ->set('assetMeta', $book)
    ->call('save');
```

Comment: Yes, that was my suspect, so I used ```'cover' => json_encode($testCover)``` although in this way the validation fails.
Although your solultion is not applicable: i should refactor the whole component. I am just slavishly following the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I found an answer: probably the objects inside the array are not parsed correctly, so if I modify my test in:

```
    /** @test */
    public function book_can_be_saved_correctly()
    {
        $admin = User::factory()->create();
        $this->actingAs($admin);

        Storage::fake('private');

        $testBook = UploadedFile::fake()->create('test_book.pdf');
        $testCover = UploadedFile::fake()->image('test_image.png');

        $emptyForm = (new UploadBookService())->buildForm();

        $book = array_merge($emptyForm,[
            'title' => 'Title Test',
            'author' => 'Author Test',
            'description' => 'Description Test',
            'publishedAt' => '2022',
        ]);

        $component = Livewire::test(UploadAsset::class)
            ->set('assetMeta', $book)
            ->set('assetMeta.book', $testBook)
            ->set('assetMeta.cover', $testCover)
            ->call('save');

            Storage::assertExists('test_book.pdf');
            Storage::assertExists('test_cover.png');
    }
```

by separately calling the `set()` for `assetMeta.book` and `assetMeta.cover` the Type error disappears.